# How to use Skip() and Take() with JQuery DataTables and generic method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

I have a view in ASP.NET MVC 5 that returns all records of an entity at once, 40,000+ records. (Lazy loading is enabled so it returns even more data than just that.) I always receive an out of memory exception, as expected. So I need to limit the data displayed but keep all of the data available to display when the page is changed or a search is performed.

This is the generic method that queries the datasource to retrieve the results. `Manager.AllAsync` is a generic Entity Framework method that queries an entity supplied through the `TEntity`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DataTableAsync<TEntity>(AlertModel alert, string viewName = null) where TEntity : class
    {
        // get data
        var data = (from a in await Manager.AllAsync<TEntity>()
                    select a).ToList();

       // create model with alert
        var response = new TableModel<TEntity> 
        {
            Alert = alert,
            Data = data
        };

        // return partial data view
       return  PartialView(viewName ?? $"_{typeof(TEntity).Name}Table", response);

    }
```

Here is the definition of `TableModel`

```
public class TableModel<TEntity>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Alert for the model.
    /// </summary>
    public AlertModel Alert { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Data from the database.
    /// </summary>
    public IList<TEntity> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the definition of `AllAsync`

```
 public virtual async Task<IList<T>> AllAsync<T>() where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            return await Context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Invalid state: {typeof(T).Name} DbSet is null.", ex);
        }
    }
```

Then the view just iterates over the records using a `foreach`.

This is how the generic DataTables JavaScript is configured:

```
function makeDataTable(id) {
var selector = '#' + id;
$(selector).DataTable({
    order: [],
    search: {
        smart: false
    },
    stateSave: true,
    deferRender: true,
    columnDefs: [{
        targets: 'no-sort',
        orderable: false
    },
    {
        targets: 'date-col',
        type: 'date',
        orderSequence: [
            'desc',
            'asc'
        ]
    }],
    lengthMenu: [
        [10, 15, 20, -1],
        [10, 15, 20, 'All']
    ]
});
$(selector).width('100%');
}
```

I'm not sure how the DataTables `Show` option communicates with the method to display only so many at once, or how to `Show All` without running into the `out of memory` exception. I know DataTables has [Server Side Processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) but the way the data is retrieved now is Linq to Entities (from the data source method). I have found some articles that explain what I should do [Like this one for example](http://technotipstutorial.blogspot.com/2017/11/part-49-pagination-using-skip-and-take.html) but this one returns a `JsonResult`. Would it be easier to make this method not so generic?

Comment: This questions is very broad, Make a get page method, pass in the page and the page size... Use Server Side Processing and pass the query parameters in

Comment: How is this question broad? It's actually quite specific....how to pass skip, take, page numbers, and show number of records per page parameters to JQuery DataTables.

Comment: it's too broad because you've presented us with a problem in which to fully answer, a user would need to 1. Write the architecture for paging (Since you only support get all). 2. Research or have prior knowledge of JQuery DataTables. 3. Write the client side  requests and create an architecture for storing the paging variables.

Comment: The architecture for paging is already supported by DataTables. Server paging - with respect to DataTables library - that doesn't max out the memory is the issue I am facing.

Comment: this issue is your pulling everything from the db in repository (anti) pattern you need to change to expose a function which accepts skip and take and use it on the iqueryable instead of ienumerable

Answer (score 0):

> You can resolve this in many ways but I gonna give you a link many
>   give some inspiration to how you kan resolve your problem ,  I'm my
>   last solution I only create a model like this
>
> Interface IDatatables  where T: class {    string request URL{get;
>   set; }
>
> ICollection Columns    Button Edit {get; set;}
>   Button Edit {get; set;}  Ect..
>
> }
>
> In the your ActionResult you need to build a class that matches the
>   request parameters of datatables  Here is some links that you can find
>   some inspiration for your integration with datatables 
>   https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-datatables-grid-with-asp-net-mvc/
>   https://gist.github.com/OllieJones/7448933cc85ee740e990383e4fded412